# How do I install a live chat to my already existing laravel web application?

Tags: laravel

I bought a laravel php template on codecanyon.net. Already installed and hosted at crytpomaxglobal.com. However I noticed it didnt come with a live chat. How do add a live chat function to my laravel web application to be able to communicate with clients?

Comment: LiveChat, Zendesk, Intercom.. the list goes on. They're all relatively easy to integrate into your website and shouldn't involve any change to Laravel/PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are looking for. If you are looking for a custom live chat solution, integrated into your application I don't think you'll be able to find anything readily available.

If you are happy to use a 3rd party SAAS provider, such as [tawk](https://www.tawk.to/) there are plenty of integrations, such as the package below:
https://github.com/emotality/tawk-laravel

Comment: This worked quite well and is more user friendly. I managed to install and test it in less than 20 mins by adding the script code through the file manager (CPanel). Apparently it also has an an android app to be able to mangae chats while on the go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple, I suggest you using facebook chat. 
1) Create a public page from your account
2) In the public page left menu click about and find your Page ID.
3) In the public page top menu go to Settings -> Messanger platform -> Whitelisted Domains, and add your domain.

Then in your main laravel template, or wherever you want this chat to be, right before closing body tag add

```
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="YOUR_PAGE_ID" theme_color="#whatever">
</div>
```

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml : true,
      version : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

For more chat customization, please check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#customization